# What makes rheoscopic particles align?

Tags: electrostatics

In a rheoscopic fluid, it is said that particles (mica traditionally) align with neighboring ones so that patterns can be seen.
What forces are responsible for the alignment ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things at work here. First of all, in the case of fluid with mica in it, the mica particles are not rounded chunks but instead tiny flat flakes. If you apply a slight shear stress to the fluid, then the flakes rotate around and tend to align themselves so the shear stress is in the direction of their flat dimension. Then there are very weak intermolecular electrostatic forces which the flat flakes exert upon one another at very close range which tend to make them remain in alignment. And since the fluid itself in which the mica flakes are floating is viscous, the flakes tend to hold their positions because the fluid damps out their movement on short distance scales.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any link ? I'll try to make them align with high voltage

Comment: sorry, no link! good luck with your experiments. -NN